# Autofill Copy down up until next empty row- Excel VBA Macro

Tags: excel, vba

i would like to paste a value in a given cell in Column A (empty column), i would like to autofill copy this down up until the next empty row or data in column B.

I can do this by specifying a range to copy down to but i would like for this to be dynamic since the amount of rows copied can be different. There are blocks of data, with a blank row in between. I would like to essentially copy and paste a value for each block of data in column A. Thank you!

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)), Type:=xlFillCopy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Column A is empty `end(xldown)` will return row 1048576. You need to look at Column B for the `end` then refer back to Column A.

You can use `offset` to grab Column B from your Selection then back to Column A.

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Selection, Selection.Offset(0, 1).End(xlDown).Offset(0, -1)), Type:=xlFillCopy
```